# Is CodeDOM my only option to do Syntax check?

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I don't actually need to RUN or even Compile a C# source code, That is done with CodeDOM. I just want a simple syntax checker that given a C# source code, be able to say Hey this ";" is missing at this line, that "(" is missing in that line, etc... What do you suggest?

Comment: Huh? Didn't you just ask the same thing [56 min ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10836961/21567). Or is this question edits going haywire?

Comment: That one got buried among so many other C# posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) for syntax checking for c# and any others.

Comment: do you know if it is TOTALLY FREE to use it in a Commercial Enterprise application?